# How to set the default value of an exposed filter rather than -Any-?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view with exposed filters in Drupal 7 and I need to set the default value of a filter to `current year`. I also need to unset/remove the `- Any -` option from the select list.

Answer (score 9):

This solution is working on **Drupal >= 8**

```
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-my-view-display') {
    $request = \Drupal::request();
    if (is_null($request->get('EXPOSED_FILTER_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME'))) {
      // get all input fields first then modify the one you want to change
      $input = $form_state->getUserInput();
      $input['EXPOSED_FILTER_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME'] = 'DEFAULT_VALUE;
      $form_state->setUserInput($input);
    }
  }
}
```

for instance, here I set the current node as the default category referenced

```
<?php
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function unsw_dev_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {

  // set default category
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    $request = \Drupal::request();
    if (is_null($request->get('field_cause_category_target_id'))) {
      $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
      if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface && $node->getType() == 'cause') {
        $form_state->setUserInput(['field_cause_category_target_id' => $node->id()]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: add `if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && isset($form['field_cause_category_target_id'] ` to protect rest of exposed filters in your website

Comment: Man you saved my life!

Comment: @DarkteK I'm glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to alter any form.

```php
function yourmodule_name_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    $form['field_width_value']['#default_value'] = 'whatever you want';
    unset($form['field_width_value']['#options']['All']);
  } 
}
```

Comment: I am getting:   [field_year_value] => Array
        (
            [#type] => select
            [#default_value] => All
            [#options] => Array
                (
                    [All] => - Any -
                    [1] => 2011
                    [2] => 2013
                    [3] => 2015
                )

            [#bef_description] => 2015
            [#description] => 2015
        ) but this is not changing my default value

Comment: $form['field_year_value']['#default_value'] = '2015'; I am using this .. but not working for me

Comment: you should use key of the value([3] => 2015).
example
$form['field_year_value']['#default_value'] = 3;

Comment: its working but only one time.. when i cleared cache.. If I select other year and then refresh page..then doesn't show default value.

Comment: Have you set remember option in views filter option?
Because my side this is working fine

Comment: If you refresh the page using f5 it will show cached form data

Comment: I need to check remember option or not?

Comment: but I need current year dynamically.. like now 2015

Comment: If you have current year on list option in your field then you can use this code
$curYear = date('Y');   
   foreach ($form['field_width_value']['#options'] as $key => $value) {
   if($value == $curYear){
     $curYearkey = $key;
   }
   }  
  $form['field_width_value']['#default_value'] = $curYearkey;

if you haven't not in your option then you should add using php on hook_form_alter.

Comment: Do note that the code as written will apply to any views exposed form, since that ID is not view specific. That probably is now what you want.

Answer (score 2):

My case scenario for a taxonomy field and filtered results, not just default value:

```
if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
  $account = user_load($user->uid);
  $country = taxonomy_term_load($account->field_country[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid']);
  $form['country']['#options'] = array($country->tid => $country->name);
  $form['country']['#default_value'] = $country->tid;
  $form_state['input']['country'] = $country->tid;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that when you change the value and submit the form it sets it back to the default value

Answer (score 1):

where are you going to set default value of current year? If you want to remove -any- from options, make it required. or use [Better Expose Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) to override the -any-.

I'm not sure if this post is your duplicate but I'm going to put my answer here also.

An expose filter but by default is the current year.

This is what you're going to do.

- Add your date field to your filter criterion
- Date selection form element: SELECT
- Filter granularity: YEAR
- Expose it
- Operator: Is equal to
- Choose "Enter Relative Date"
- Type this: now

First Part:

[image]

Second Setting:
[image]

Expose Filter with Default Value

[image: Expose Filter with default]

Is this what you want?

Comment: I want to remove -any- from options. And my filter like this:year[2014][2015][2016] something like this. I need to set by defualt value current year .

Comment: I edited my answer, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Having also this need I just found this module: [Views Advanced Labels](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_advanced_labels) and successfully used it, replacing the - Any - by a custom simple text for 2 exposed filters in the same view.

It says that it works with tokens. So I guess using `[date:custom:Y]` or maybe creating a date format could be an option.

Some more resources here: [Auto update to the current year in the copyright footer (© 2010-2013)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1872412)

Answer (score -2):

This is my solution; it works for Drupal 7 too.

```php
function my_theme_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    $form['**FIELD_ID**']['#options']['All'] = '**YOUR TEXT**';
  }
}
```

Comment: Implementing a `hook_form_alter` is discouraged. Hooks implemented on any theme should be theme-related, any other feature should be covered by modules.