# Change label "-Month" in Month

Tags: views

I have an issue that needs the help of everyone. I created the page in view to filter the node. I created a filter **Date created** in "view exposed filter" for filter by  **Date created**.

I configured for the Filter granularity is check month,  that filter will display 2 dropbox to me to choose, i.e. month and year dropbox. But I want to change label in this two dropbox. Example: "- Month -" replace for "-Month". Do not know if anyone can help me handle the matter.

[image][image]

Comment: Mod closing topic help, Please

Comment: check [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/155176/how-to-set-default-value-for-expose-filter-rater-than-any)